# Why is "chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener" an anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

so I'm trying to build my first google chrome extension and I'm running into difficulties.

I'm trying to handle receiving messages from content scripts. I keep getting this error from google extensions:

background.js:22 (anonymous function)

This is what my code looks like:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
"name": "Getting Started Example",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Build an Extension!",
"permissions": ["activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "clipboardWrite", "clipboardRead","declarativeContent"],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
"content_scripts": [ {
    "matches": ["http://*/*"],
    "js": ["content.js", "jquery-1.4.2.min.js"]
}],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/get_started16.png",
        "32": "images/get_started32.png",
        "48": "images/get_started48.png",
        "128": "images/get_started128.png"
      }
},
"icons": {
    "16": "images/get_started16.png",
    "32": "images/get_started32.png",
    "48": "images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "images/get_started128.png"
  },
"manifest_version": 2
 }
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.event == "copy") {
            alert("copy detected");
            console.log("copy");
        }
    sendResponse({});
    }
);
```

**content.js**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({event: "copy"}, function(response) {
    console.log('from content_script: copied!');
});
```

Why is this considered an anonymous function? I checked documentation as to whether or not I had to add something to permissions, but documentation said it should be good.

Comment: anonymous functions are functions without a name. The error simply indicates there is error at certain line in one of the functions that's declared without a name. In your example, this would be the function that you pass to addListener as callback. So check the code inside the function to find the cause of error.

Comment: A function without a name is anonymous. This is how JavaScript works. BTW don't use alerts, use devtools debugger for the background page where you can set breakpoints and inspect variables.

Comment: @gp. Oh okay! how exactly do i find the error in the callback function? I tried following an example that uses chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener to see if i have any syntactic errors but I'm still getting the error that its an anonymous function. i.e. I changed sendResponse({}) so that it had an actual response, ie sendResponse({response: "responded"}) but im still getting "anonymous function"

Comment: this might help https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tut_debugging

Answer (score 0):

Anonimous functions are not allowed in chrome extensions (since manifest 3?)

So you have to "fix" them. Also check if is being **called as declared**

Just replace in your js (background.js in your case)

```
(function(*request, sender, sendResponse*){...} )**()**
```

to

```
function myspecialfunction(*request, sender, sendResponse*){....}
```

And if it was called as declared, remember to use it